# WSO2 ESB Plugin Development

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I would like to use WSO2 ESB solution for communication of two service (obviously no surprise)  one end point is using REST services for communication with outside world. Here is the problem starts. Since I am a new one I am not sure where to start. I read about WSO2 ESB some but to be able start quickly your ramp up refferances would be quite  helpful.

The service I would like to talk to is called BeBanjo.